# Combine Laravel 5 with non-laravel pages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building an application in Laravel which will be in construction for some time. In the meantime, I have 2 "conventional" websites, one static html and one php, which I'd like to include in my source control and make publicly accessible as I build the laravel application.

I have my public folder set up like this :

> public/website1/many folders and files
>
> public/website2/many folders and files
>
> public/index.php

I would like to route / redirect users in the following way (lets use my development environment "localhost" as the domain):

> localhost/laravelapp/ -> index.php
>
> localhost/website1/ -> website1/index.html
>
> localhost/website2/ -> website2/index.php

This way I can maintain all my code within a single project / source control / server.

But how do I route this!?

I have tried:

```
Route::get('/website1', function() {
  return File::get(public_path() . '/website1/index.html');
});
```

but this just returns a static file with no relative links to the css folder or other linked files. How can I redirect the user properly to the correct area? Rebuilding the existing sites in Laravel framework is not an option. Thanks.

Comment: basic concept behind the laravel is his component, you can use easily components in your non-laravel pages by just calling in your page like 'use Illuminate\Contracts\Logging\Log as Log'  for logging functionality however you can study laravel api for further assistance.

Comment: I also found the `https://github.com/mattstauffer/IlluminateNonLaravel` for use laravel outside of your application. This package can give basic idea to use laravel components if you do not want to use this package.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use laravel components in my non-laravel pages - i simply want to redirect from my laravel application to a standard website / set of pages within my public folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by by doing a couple of things:

1) VirtualHosts on the webserver to handle the domain name routing. Create a file on the Apache server:

> httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName domain1.com
ServerAlias dev.domain1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName domain2.com
ServerAlias dev.domain2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public/website2    
</VirtualHost>
```

This routed my domains to their subfolders

2) The localhost environment was not working well. I switched from using "php -S server.php" (Laravels own server script configuration) to MAMP for OSX. This instantly cleared up my remaining permissions issues.

I hope this answer can help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 3):

This should be pretty simple. I assume that you are using apache?
If you put a separate `.htaccess` file inside `public/website1` and `public/website2` then those rules will apply instead when you are visiting those routes, ignoring the rewrite rules in `public/.htaccess`.
You can configure your new .htaccess-files however you want, but all you need is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
```

This is rerouted on the webserver level. Nothing is passed through laravel. This is what you want.

---

Now, we have solved this part:

> localhost/website1/ -> website1/index.html
>
> localhost/website2/ -> website2/index.php

But the laravel app acts like this:

> localhost/ -> index.php

instad of:

> localhost/laravelapp/ -> index.php

To solve this part, create a new directory inside public called `laravelapp`
and move `public/.htaccess` to `public\laravelapp\.htaccess` and change the following line

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^ ../index.php [L]
```

Comment: This is still not working as expected. With the .htaccess files in place just as you suggest i'm afraid. I get a "404 Not Found" when I visit "localhost/website1/". And when I visit "localhost/website2/" i get the index page in the root of my laravel app! (not the welcome page, the actual root of the app). Localhost/public gives the laravel welcome page. Anything within laravel/public (ie localhost/public/website1/) ALSO gives the welcome page (which is the index page of the public folder). What the hell is going on!?